# How to programmatically bind a property?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

This is my code:

```
using MySqlConnector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace Flanium_Agent
{
    public class Agency
    {
        public string Station { get; set; }
        public string Process { get; set; }
        public string Actions { get; set; }
        public string Started { get; set; }
        public string Finished { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public MySqlConnection connection =new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User ID=root;Database=orchestration_db");

        private Grid DisplayGrid { get; set; }

        private Border border { get; set; }

        public Grid getDisplayGrid()
        {
            return DisplayGrid;
        }
        public Agency InsertAgentToGrid(Grid grid)
        {

            DisplayGrid = new Grid();
            
            var headerRowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
            headerRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(50);
            DisplayGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(headerRowDefinition);

            for (var index = 0; index < GetType().GetProperties().Length; index++)
            {
                var property = GetType().GetProperties()[index];
                var header = new TextBlock();
                var column = new ColumnDefinition();
                header.Text = property.Name;
                header.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                header.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                header.FontSize = 16;
                Grid.SetRow(header, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(header, index);

                DisplayGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
                DisplayGrid.Children.Add(header);
            }

            var contentRowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
            contentRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(50);
            DisplayGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(contentRowDefinition);

            for (var index = 0; index < GetType().GetProperties().Length; index++)
            {
                var propertyValue = GetType().GetProperties()[index];
                var content = new TextBlock();
                
                //content.Text = propertyValue.GetValue(this).ToString();
                content.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                content.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                content.FontSize = 12;
                Grid.SetRow(content, 1);
                Grid.SetColumn(content, index);
                DisplayGrid.Children.Add(content);
                
                var myBinding = new Binding(propertyValue.Name)
                {
                    Source = this
                };
                content.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);

            }

            DisplayGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            DisplayGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            DisplayGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 25, 0, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(DisplayGrid);
            
            connection.Open();
            //create new thread with UpdateAgent()
            Task.Run(UpdateAgent);
            

            return this;
        }

        public void UpdateAgent()
        {
            try
            {

                var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM agents WHERE station='" + Station + "'", connection);
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
                reader.Read();
                Station = reader.GetString(0);
                Process = reader.GetString(1);
                Actions= reader.GetString(2);
                Started = reader.GetString(3);
                Finished = reader.GetString(4);
                Status = reader.GetString(5);
                reader.Close();

                
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Task.Run(UpdateAgent);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                    
            }
        }
        public Agency(string station, string process, string actions, string started, string finished, string status)
        {
            try
            {
                Station = station;
                Process = process;
                Actions = actions;
                Started = started;
                Finished = finished;
                Status = status;

                connection.Open();

                var cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO agents (station, process, actions, started, finished, status) VALUES (@station, @process, @actions, @started, @finished, @status)", connection);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@station", station);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process", process);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actions", actions);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@started", started);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finished", finished);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }

        public void RemoveAgent()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                connection.Open();

                using var cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM agents WHERE station = @station", connection);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@station", Station);
            
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                connection.Close();
                
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

I can confirm that the binding is set properly from these lines:

```
        var myBinding = new Binding(propertyValue.Name)
        {
            Source = this
        };
        content.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Because even though I do not set the text property to a value with this: content.Text = propertyValue.GetValue(this).ToString(); because it is commented, the text value is still being updated.

However.. I have a recursive method that runs once every 1000ms called UpdateAgent(), this method reads from an mySQL Database and updates the class, now this is where I can't figure out why this text property of the content TextBlock will not update even though the class properties have, even with a binding already set.

I have already browsed and looked for duplicates but could not find anything relevant or anyone who tried using a recursive method to fetch data from an SQL database and their bindings not updating etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF has no way of knowing that the property changed, and thus that the Binding is out-of-date.

You should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0) on the `Agency` class and broadcast an event when any property changes. As an optimisation, if you know you're changing all the properties at once, you can raise a single event (instead of one per property).

```cs
public class Agency : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void UpdateAgent()
    {
        // ... elided for clarity

        // set all properties
        Station = reader.GetString(0);
        Process = reader.GetString(1);
        Actions= reader.GetString(2);
        Started = reader.GetString(3);
        Finished = reader.GetString(4);
        Status = reader.GetString(5);

        // ** ADD THIS CODE **
        // raise the PropertyChanged event so WPF updates bindings
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(""));

        // ... elided for clarity
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, this worked exceptionally well. This doesn't seem to freeze the UI Thread either, or it does but it is not something that can be felt at a significant level.